# The use of "EDIT" and other similar monikers in Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, edits

OK.  I understand that discouraging "EDIT" in Stack Overflow posts is a bit controversial.  Even though questions should read like actual questions, and answers should read like actual answers (and not news tickers).  Even though we already have detailed, comprehensive edit histories that already perform the same function.  I've posted at least once on Meta about this, and there are always complaints about my stance.  People are really attached to their EDITs.

But what about Documentation?

Surely a Documentation article really should read like a book chapter or small article.  Does anyone who considers themselves a serious writer ever put EDITs in their books or articles?  Does anyone who contributes to Documentation genuinely consider EDITs a viable technique?

**Example**
https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/design-patterns/1720/decorator-pattern/5558/vendingmachinedecorator#t=201610161419009747322

(Note: There are some blog writers who do, in fact, use EDITs.  However, I'm willing to, at least for purposes of this discussion, label them as "not serious writers," or at least "using blogs that don't have adequate tools, like edit histories.")

Comment: ... what are you talking about? What are "EDIT"s and how does that differ from "edit"s?

Comment: @NicolBolas: See the example I linked, about halfway down.  EDIT: This is what I mean.

Comment: In other words, meta edits, edits about edits, and the favorite of all: UPDATE.

Comment: These monikers are useless fluff in Q and A (though I'm probably guilty of it too.) For blogs, it can occasionally make sense, especially when they have supporting comments. In docs it makes even less sense as there are no comments to suggest why an edit was made. I say get rid of them in docs.

Comment: @DavidG Not sure about 'useless fluff in Q and A'. I use them to indicate I've added something new to an answer to help the OP notice the update. It's usually when they later provide additional info that changes the question somewhat. But totally agree that it doesn't belong in the docs.

Comment: In Q&A, the value of an "Edit: I did _this_ and _this_ and _this_." sentence or short paragraph is that it provides a concise edit summary, without the reader having to actually _check_ the edit history.  In Documentation... all it does is look unprofessional.

Comment: @KScandrett If answers have "EDIT" tags in them, that's *almost always* just a symptom of the question not being good enough in the first place. Documentation doesn't have that situation as the domain is already very well defined.

Comment: Imagine if MSDN, MDN, and even the C++, ECMA (all the different ECMA standards), HTML and CSS language specifications were all littered with these EDIT zones.

Comment: @BoltClock: Well, the specs *do* sometimes mention that previous versions defined X that is no longer defined... e.g HTTP 306 response.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy: Yeah but at least it's not tacked on with a big fat EDIT stamp.

Comment: @BoltClock it is a nightmare.

Answer (score 37):

I agree. Marking an edit using the actual text "EDIT" or "UPDATE" or "I MADE AN EDIT BECAUSE THIS WAS WRONG BEFORE BUT SINCE I CHANGED IT IT'S NOW CORRECT. HAVE A NICE DAY AND THANKS IN ADVANTAGE :)" is unnecessary and should be removed when found. I've always simply made edits on Stack Overflow, with no prelude, introduction, or other fanfare in the edit itself. I do, however, include verbose edit summaries when editing questions and answers, and do the same in Documentation.

Answer (score 13):

People do this!?! SMH.

This is ridiculous, the whole concept behind docs is that it be a more canonical(-ish) document than referring to questions or answers to questions. When doc is updated it does not need to present the history of that update to the regular reader (I think Q&A is different in this respect). It is not needed because a reader is already reading the latest edit, they do not need to be explicitly advised that it is an edit, the fact is implicit and expected.

Comment: I just had to upvote this only because it conveys exactly the sort of exasperation I felt.

Answer (score -2):

No need for "EDIT" when the change is in the documentation only.

However, I would very much like notes about version changes in the software being documented. This can be written out in the text so that it reads nicely, like a book as you said. For example: "Until XYZ version 6.15, this function only supported operation A." While these are also visible in the edit history, I consider them often important enough to be pointed out explicitly.

Comment: You can do that without using EDITs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It does, but it's [not exactly obvious](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N0C4.png) (right now)

Comment: @DavidG [what?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwknd.png)